# One line shell command that finds all students in LEC05 and prints their first name in sorted order

Tags: bash, text-processing, command-line, grep, sort

For example suppose we have a file called `input.txt` which contains

`100 John Doe LEC05 12356`

`132 Carol Bon LEC05 156`

`122 Cavar Liktik LEC01 136`

`...`

This command should find everyone in `LEC05` and print out their first names in `sorted` order in a file called `output.txt`

The command should be a one-line command (with pipes).

I'm not sure how it would be done.

`see if LEC05 | find first name at index 1 | sort < input.txt > output.txt`

How do I do the `see if LEC05 | find first name at index 1` part?

Comment: I'm not sure of the command I mention in the last line, I want to try that but I don't know what command that would be

Comment: Two ways:  `grep LEC05` will work but may have a false positive if someone's creative parents have given you a 'LEC05 Smith' in your roster.  `awk '$4 == "LEC05" {print [...]}'` will work unless you have a 'John Wilkes Booth' in your roster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '$4 == "LEC05" { print $2 }' /path/to/inputfile | sort > outputfile
```

With `grep` and `cut`:

```
grep 'LEC05' /path/to/inputfile | cut -f2 | sort > outputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

More awk-ness

```
     awk '/LEC05/{ name[$2]++ } END { n = asorti( name,sname ); for ( i in sname ) print sname[i]}' input.txt
```